# Consequence of removing iPhone from list of trusted devices

Tags: iphone, ios, security

If I remove an iPhone from the list of trusted devices in AppleID does the pin code set for that phone still work and protect the phone?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the phone code (i.e. the code to unlock your phone) remains the same and still works. The main difference in future will be that for every 2-factor authentication you can not use this iPhone any more. I.e. when you want to sign in to iCloud on a different device, you have no option to allow that login from this iPhone, which means you need a third device.